# Is there a way to find out information on battery through macbook serial number?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, hardware, battery, serial-number

i bought my MBP Retina display 13"(late 2013) 5 months ago; a week ago i had to change its battery at an authorised reseller when my small sister accidentally dropped a whole glass of water on it.
i think my new battery isn't the same as the one i had before.
i paid a LOT of money to get it fixed...
my question is: is there any way i can find out my old battery's information and/or serial # through my MBP's serial number?
or if anyone has the same mac model would you be kind enough to share your battery(original) information?

MacBook Information: MacBook Pro Core i5 2.6 13" Retina Late 2013

Current Battery Information:

Model Information:

Serial Number:

Manufacturer: SMP

Device Name:  bq20z45  (i researched and there should be a 1 after the 5)

Pack Lot Code:    0

PCB Lot Code: 0

Firmware Version: 702

Hardware Revision:    3

Cell Revision:    379

Charge Information:

Charge Remaining (mAh):   3870

Fully Charged:    No

Charging: No

Full Charge Capacity (mAh): 6211  (I believe this should be around 8000)

Health Information:

Cycle Count:  3

Condition:    Normal

Battery Installed:    Yes

Amperage (mA):    -485

Voltage (mV): 11772

Any information is much appreciated :)

Comment: Simple check! does the new battery has a Apple logo on it?

Comment: Why do you need to know the information of the old battery, particularly the serial?

Comment: @Buscar im not sure at all, i did not see the battery before it was placed

Comment: @Stuart H because i want to know if the new battery is legit ; if i had information on my old battery, i would compare it with the new battery. Then i'd put my mind at rest if the info. Matched :)

Comment: @MiriamHatem, that may work but often parts from Apple's production channels will have different serial compositions to parts from their spares channel, so even though the AASP fitted a genuine Apple part, due to the fact that it's from the spares channel it might not fit the same serial pattern as your previous battery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, information would not be attainable simply through the serial number. It is unlikely that you obtained the incorrect battery, since AASP's source their parts from Apple to perform warranty-service repairs. I poked around online and noted that you are not the only one who has the bq20z45 part number from SMP, nor the only one to have a Full Charge Capacity different than ~8000. I found this via various user screenshots on [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00964ZPKQ).

Likely, the battery is correct for your unit and will function as expected. If not, all warranty repair services are either covered by your Applecare Protection Plan or, if out of warranty, 90 days from date of service. Should you continue to have concerns, I'd call the AASP back to verify that you got the right item.

EDIT: It may be worth it for you to calibrate your battery. Charge all the way to 100%, then unplug the unit and use it until it dies w/o charging it up again. Repeat once and that should get your battery reporting accurately as well.

Comment: @smooosher There is an addition: i researched the device name bq20z45, & it stated that it lasts for 400 to 600 cycles; while apple says that their batteries last for about 1000 cycles (those having device number of bq20z451). Through coconutbattery, (app that tells you details about the status of your battery) i noticed the charge capacity slowly dropping to 6000 and rising around 6200 in the past few days; and the full charge capacity percentage also dropping to 97% when it should stay at 100% given it is a new battery. Also, i would appreciate it if you took the time and called the AASP..